# Where to generate unique IDs for entities in a redux application?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, api-design, redux-thunk

I want to allow users to add the same server Item to the page multiple times (id: 5). To keep track of these Items in our application, we need to generate a unique ID for each instance.

Our item has relational data, so for performance reasons we might normalize the API response in a redux store.

```
type Item = { id: string; }
type Sku = { id: string; }

type AppStore = {
  items: { [id: string]: Items },
  skus: { [id: string]: Skus },
  itemSkus: { [id: string]: string[] },
}
```

Working with this API

```
export interface IAPIResponse<T> {
  data?: T;
  errors?: string[];
}

type IAPIItem = {
  id: string;
  skus: Array<{
    id: string;
  }>;
}
```

Requesting the data in a typical redux-thunk action creator:

```
export const addItem = () => async (dispatch) => {
  dispatch(startedAddItem());
  try {
    const response = await get <IAPIResponse<IAPIItem>>('/get/item/5');
    dispatch(succeededAddItem(response));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error', error);
    dispatch(failedAddItem(error));
  }
};
```

And populate our reducers with their relevant data:

```
// items reducer
case ItemAction.addSucceeded:
  const apiItem = getApiResource(action.payload);
  const apiErrors = getApiErrors(action.payload);

  if (apiErrors) // Handle errors in state

  if (apiItem) {
    const item = buildItem(apiItem);
    return {
      ...state,
      [item.id]: item,
    }
  }
  break;

// skus reducer
case ItemAction.addSucceeded:
  const apiItem = getApiResource(action.payload);
  const apiErrors = getApiErrors(action.payload);

  if (apiErrors) // Handle errors in state

  if (apiItem) {
    const skus = buildSkus(apiItem.skus);
    const indexedSkus = { ...skus.map(s => ({ [s.id]: s })) };
    return {
      ...state,
      ...indexedSkus,
    }
  }
  break;

// itemSkus reducer
case ItemAction.addSucceeded:
  const apiItem = getApiResource(action.payload);
  const apiErrors = getApiErrors(action.payload);

  if (apiErrors) // Handle errors in state

  if (apiItem) {
    const item = buildLineItem(apiItem);
    const skus = buildSkus(apiItem.skus);

    return {
      [item.id]: skus.map(s => s.id),
    }
  }
  break;
```

In this pattern we couldn't reliable generate the same unique ids for Item and Skus because the response is being parsed in multiple reducers. Redux suggests we must generate the unique ID before it hits the reducers.

**Question:** How can I adapt this pattern to parse the response before the reducer, while maintaining the flexibility to read nested api data and parse response body errors in the reducers?

Comment: I'm rather confused by the "store item with multiple instances" comment. Can you add some further explanation for what you're trying to do, and why/how?

Comment: @markerikson Sorry, I've updated that part :) Imagine you are building a car and want to add four tires. The tires have the same ID on server. But in our client application, we need to generate a unique id for each tire to keep track of it.

Comment: So from an app user flow, where in this sequence are you needing to start using these IDs? Are the "multiple instances" actually something that's coming back from the server, or are they being added over time on the client based on user interaction (ie, "add front left tire")?

Comment: @markerikson They are coming back from the server, ie. User clicks "add tire" then a dialog appears where they select a pre-existing tire from the database. So they add four of the same tire. I would need to generate the ID before adding the tire to the redux store

Comment: So is the server actually returning `tires: [{}, {}, {}, {}]`?  If so, why not have the server generate those unique IDs?  Or am I misunderstanding the usage here? (Also note that this might be easier to discuss over in the Reactiflux `#redux` channel for the moment).

Comment: The server would return 1 tire at a time, for each "add tire" action. The user likely will add the same tire to each corner of that car. So we now have 4 instances of the same tire in our application. Having the server generate the ID would solve the issue. But from my understanding, the API shouldn't care that the client needs unique ids. From an API perspective, if you request the same object twice, you should get the same object twice. I joined the discord!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further discussion on Discord, the OP provided this key bit of information:

> There's really only one data flow piece here
>
> - The React application can request a tire from database when user clicks "add tire" (`/tire/add/5`)
> - They can request the same tire multiple times
> - They can then modify each instance of that tire to have unique properties
> - Click "save" will send the car and its tires to `/car/save`

My answer:

The `/tire/add` API endpoint could just generate a UUID every time it sends a response. Or, on the client side:

```js
const addTire = (sku, otherData) => {
  const response = await post(`/tire/add/${sku}`, otherData);
  response.data.id = uuid();
  dispatch(tireAdded(response.data));
}
```

or alternately, especially if you're using RTK:

```js
const tiresSlice = createSlice({
  name: "tires",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    tireAdded: {
      reducer(state, action) {
        // whatever here
      },
      prepare(tireData) {
        return {
          payload: {...tireData, id: uuid()}
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Overall:

- don't do anything random in reducers
- that means generating any random stuff *before* you dispatch
- you can preprocess and modify and mangle API responses as much as you want before dispatching an action containing that data

Comment: You recommend generating random IDs such that they are passed as part of the payload, not generated in the reducer?

Comment: Yes, because generating _any_ random values in a reducer makes it non-predictable, and random number generation is considered a "side effect": https://redux.js.org/style-guide/style-guide#reducers-must-not-have-side-effects . Now, will the code _run_ if you generate random numbers in a reducer? Sure. But it's not the preferred approach.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I suppose a UI component may need to bear responsibility for ensuring global uniqueness of any id then? Seems like something better left to a reducer.

Comment: Definitely not what I was suggesting :) For example, if you need to have a unique ID generated each time you dispatch an "item added" action, you can do that in an action creator. Since RTK generates action creators for you, it provides "prepare callbacks" as a way to do that: https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-4-using-data#preparing-action-payloads

Comment: Aha! I see the difference now. Thank you :)